# How to write streamlit UploadedFile to temporary directory with original filename?

Tags: streamlit

Streamlit has a function that allows convenient upload of multiple files.

```
files = st.file_uploader('File upload', type=['txt'],accept_multiple_files=True)
```

Then `files` contains a list of `UploadedFile` objects which are `ByteIO` like. Though it is not clear how to get the filenames of the original files and write the file to a temporary directory. It is also not clear if that approach would conflict with the way streamlit operates. It basically reruns the underlying script every time an action is performed.

I am using some tools that read files based on their path given as a string. They are expected to be read from the hard drive.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the name of the file with `files[i].name` and its content with `files[i].read()`.

It looks like this in the end:

```py
import os
import streamlit as st

files = st.file_uploader("File upload", type=["txt"], accept_multiple_files=True)

if len(files) == 0:
    st.error("No file were uploaded")

for i in range(len(files)):
    bytes_data = files[i].read()  # read the content of the file in binary
    print(files[i].name, bytes_data)
    with open(os.path.join("/tmp", files[i].name), "wb") as f:
        f.write(bytes_data)  # write this content elsewhere
```